# Conditional CSS selector based on state of DOM

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following piece of code that I am trying to style:

```
<div class="group">
    <div class="tabs">
        <access type="full">
            <span class="tab">Hello</span>
        </access>
        <span class="tab">World!</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This HTML will change depending on a Router Guard but at any given moment, I'd like for each of the tabs to have a `20px` margin in between them as well as the first one having a left-margin of 0.

My confusion stems from the fact that the first child of `tabs` will either be a component of type `access` or just a normal `span`.

So here is what I'm trying to do:

```
/* Set every tab to have 20px spacing in between */
.tab {
    margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}

/* Select first child of tabs, whether access component or span and sets margin to 0 */
.tabs > *:nth-child(1) span:first-child,
.tabs span:first-child {
    margin: 0
}
```

My reasoning is that for the first portion of the second style, `.tabs > *:nth-child(1) span:first-child,` it reads:

> Pick the first child of tabs and select the first span child

And the second to read:

> Pick the first span child of `tabs`

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: What does `<access>` tag come from?

Comment: It is a custom Angular component

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:first-child` to get the first tag inside `.tabs` and then apply `margin:0;` to it and and spans inside it:

```
.tab{

  margin: 0 0 0 20px;
}

.tabs > :first-child,
.tabs > :first-child span{
  margin:0;
}
```

This covers both `<access>` and `<span>` being the first child.

[example codepen](https://codepen.io/Arcath/pen/OEXyPL)

Answer (score 0):

```
.tabs span:first-child
```

This is a direct superset of

```
.tabs > *:nth-child(1) span:first-child
```

because of the descendant combinator before `span:first-child`, meaning that it ends up matching the inner `span:first-child` as well, which is not what you want.

Generally if you're using the `>` combinator to distinguish children from grandchildren, you should use it everywhere to maintain consistency and avoid mistakes like this.

On a side note, `:nth-child(1)` is equivalent to `:first-child` and it's a good idea to stick to one again for the sake of consistency.

Your selector should be

```
.tabs > *:first-child > span:first-child,
.tabs > span:first-child
```

Answer (score 0):

In my approach, I add the margin to the right on each tab that way the 1st one does not have the `ml:20px` but all `.tabs` are separated by 20px.

```css
.tabs .tab {
  margin-right: 20px;
}

access {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="group">
  <div class="tabs">
    <access type="full">
      <span class="tab">Hello</span>
    </access>
    <span class="tab">World!</span>
  </div>
</div>
```